# ¿Cómo podría acceder a los datos json de un array response de una API en PHP?

Tags: php, api, php7

**ACTUALIZACIÓN DE CÓDIGO Y DE DUDA**

*NEW_ Tras probar algunas de las soluciones que me habéis dado, me he topado con que al acceder al array de `number` no me devuelve un valor booleano, me da un `1` sea, cual sea los dígitos que ponga. Concretamente sucede en `luhn`. Dejo aquí el code.

*OLD_ he conseguido hacer la conexión con la API y que me muestre valores individuales, pero ahora, no sé como podría acceder a los valores que están contenidos en un array que son los que verdaderamente me interesan, me explico. Supongamos que la respuesta JSON de la api da los siguientes datos:

```
"number": {
"length": 16,
"luhn": true
}


    $bin = $_POST['card'];
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://lookup.binlist.net/'.$bin.''), true );
$lhn = $data['number']['luhn'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Iframe de procesamiento de pago </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $lhn;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Cabe destacar de que soy **MUY NUEVO** en PHP y sobretodo en el ámbito de API, pues hoy me ha surgido la idea de aprender a usarlo.
Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo (según el ejemplo) que recibes un json con esta estructura:

```
{"number":{"lenght":16,"luhn":true}}
```

Tienes dos opciones según te interese tratar los datos, lo conviertes en un objeto o en un array.

**Un objeto**

Tiene esta estructura:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'number' => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'lenght' => int 16
      public 'luhn' => boolean true
```

Se accede al valor de esta forma;

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($json);
echo $jsonObject->number->luhn;
```

**Un array**

Tiene esta estructura:

```
array (size=1)
  'number' => 
    array (size=2)
      'lenght' => int 16
      'luhn' => boolean true
```

Se accede al valor de esta forma:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
echo $jsonArray['number']['luhn'];
```

Independientemente de si es un objeto o un array, hay que acceder a través de su jerarquía, con la sintaxis que cada uno tiene.

Comment: Holaa, la verdad que funciona perfecto, pero en el caso de `number` concretamente en `lenght` y `luhn` en vez de devolverme un valor boolean, me devuelve un 1.
Actualizo el código

Comment: @low_aortical_supremassy los valores boleanos son equivalentes a integer 1 (true) e integer 0 (false).

Comment: El problema es que me devuelve true siempre, aún no pasando el check "luhn"

Comment: Ah, nada. Es problema de la API, que pone todo como válido a nivel de ese check.

Comment: @low_aortical_supremassy Me alegro de que se solucionara

Answer (score 1):

Si solo es acceder a la variable de un array (un registro) seria lo siguiente:

```
$variable = '{"id":1, "nombre":"Juan"}'
//Conviertes el JSONARRAY a un array común en PHP
$array = json_decode($_POST['variable '],TRUE);
//Guardas el valor `nombre` en otra variable
$valor=$array[`nombre`];
echo $valor;
```

Pero si son varios registros, es decir, varios arrays dentro del array, debes iterar con un for o foreach:

```
//El JSONARRAY original
$variable = '[{"id":1, "nombre":"Juan"},{"id":2, "nombre":"Manuel"}]';
//La transformacion de JSONARRAY a array en PHP
$arr=json_decode($variable,TRUE);
//Imprime el valor 'nombre' de cada array interno
for($i=0;i<count($arr);$i++){
    echo $arr[$i]['nombre'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay principalmente dos problemas en tu código:

1. No estás creando un HTML válido y esto podría traerte problemas en contextos en los que se haga una validación estricta de HTML. En la respuesta veremos el código incorporado en un HTML completo, poniendo la parte de PHP dentro del `body`, que es donde suele ir.
2. Tú estas creando un array llamado `$output`  y dentro de él intentas asignar una llave que se llamaría también `$output`, pero esto es incorrecto en sí mismo (el array tendría una clave que sería el mismo ¿?), y además, `$output` no existiría en ese momento. Además, ese proceso no es necesario porque los datos con los que necesitarías trabajar ya están en la variable `$data`.

Aplicando lo dicho, así debería funcionar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AQUÍELTITULODETUPAGINA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    $bin = $_POST['card'];
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://lookup.binlist.net/'.$bin.''), true );
    $validate = $data['number']['luhn'];  
    var_dump($validate) ; #bool(true)
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si tú pasas `false` a `json_decode`, entonces obtendrás un objeto, y la forma de lectura cambia en ese sentido:

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://lookup.binlist.net/'.$bin.''), false );
$validate = $data->number->luhn;  
var_dump($validate) ; #bool(true)
```

Asumimos que en `$data` estás recibiendo una respuesta con esta estructura:

```
{
  "number":{
    "length":16,
    "luhn":true
  }
}
```

Digo esto porque el JSON que muestras en la pregunta NO es un JSON válido.